# Haptic feedback instead of "touch sounds"?

Tags: samsung, 7.1-nougat, vibration, haptic-feedback

On my Galaxy S7, under *Settings → Sounds and Vibration → System*, I have the option to

- enable haptic feedback (vibration) for home-button, back-button and recents-button
- enable "touch sounds", i.e. a clicking sounds when the touch-screen registers a press on a GUI button (automatically disabled when turning the phone to vibration mode or silent mode). Even on the lowest possible "System" volume, these are still a bit loud for an office environment.

Is it possible, on Android in general or on the Galaxy S7 specifically, to replace the "touch-sounds" by haptic feedback?

[image: The "Sounds & Vibration" settings interface.]

Note that the "keyboard" settings at the end of the dialog affect only the preinstalled Samsung keyboard (which I don't use), and not GUI buttons.

Comment: what do you mean by **replace touch sounds by haptic feedback**?

Comment: @global_warming I believe kdb wants to get haptic feedback for all screen touches, not just for the navigation buttons.

Comment: @DanHulme That's correct. The settings don't seem to give such an option however, so I wanted to see if I am missing something.